# Помогите задать pattern validation

Tags: jquery, валидация

Нужно чтобы могли быть введены только русские или английские буквы в верхнем и нижнем регистре, а также символы пробел или дефис.

Для валидации использую *jquery validation*.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось, спасибо!

```js
$.validator.addMethod("regx", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
    return regexpr.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid name.");
```

И потом:

```js
$( "#formHD" ).validate({
rules: {
form_name: {
required: true,
regx: /^[a-zа-яё\-\s]+$/iu

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте эту регулярку `/^[a-zа-яё\-\s]+$/iu`

Comment: Осталось понять, как добавить эту регулярку в плагин, ибо напрямую, через <input>, игнорируется...

Comment: @DaniilFironov вот здесь написанно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation